# Oracle Virtual Box: Windows 8 host, Ubuntu VM shared folder mount fails

Tags: 12.04, mount, virtualbox, windows-8

I am really desperate - today I wanted to reinstall my Ubuntu VM on a Windows 8 host and followed exactely the same procedure as I did last time. But now I can no longer share a folder between Windows 8 and Ubuntu. 
I try to share my Windows 8 folder with name NAME like this:

- I select it as shared folder in the settings (auto-mount and permanent >> in Ubuntu I find the correctly created folder sf_NAME in /media)
- Then in the terminal in the VM I use:

  cd /media

  sudo mkdir NAME

  sudo mount -t vboxsf NAME /media/NAME

This results in the error message

```
re 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /media/NAME, 
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try 
dmesg | tail or so
```

**EDIT: FIXED**

This fixed it for me

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Source: [Guest Additions not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452649/guest-additions-not-working?newreg=0f95393bf89c43028aba86b43f9b5ea6)

Comment: you could answer your own question if you have found one, instead of appending an EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [reported bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12879) in the current version of Virtualbox where a symlink is not created during the VBoxGuestAdditions installation.

Run this command in terminal to create the missing link, then re-run your mount command and it should work correctly.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

Comment: According to the ticket, this is fixed in 4.3.11 - whenever it's released. Thanks for pointing this out